# How do out of phase tell us the amplitude of gravitational wave?

Tags: gravitational-waves, phase-transition, ligo

When gravitational waves hit the 2 mirrors in [LIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) and causes the signals to switch between in-phase and out-of-phase, it should only show the changes in frequency. What about the amplitude of the wave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes in the interference pattern are due to changes in the distances between the mirrors, shifting by a fraction of a wavelength. The oscillating fractional change in this distance tells you the amplitude of the metric perturbation.

Answer (score 1):

They are not looking at *amplitude*. They are looking into time-frequency domain, where they have density of energy per 1 s and per 1 Hz. Technically they have J/s/Hz (Joule per s per Hz).

They see both changes in frequency and in time. But it does not make a task easier because majority of singals is just noise and they filter it all by very complex constructions and computer pattern recognition.